# Prove that a power series $f(x)$ satisfies $-f''(x) + x^2f(x) = 3f(x) \ \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, power-series

> Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of a power series defined as
>   $$
> f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n+1}}{n!}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}
> $$
>
> **Question:**
>
> Find the Power series for $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ and prove that 
>   $$
> -f''(x) + x^2f(x) = 3f(x) \ \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}
> $$

In an earlier question I have argued for that $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ as we have a Power Series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$ with $a = 0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and convergence radius $R = \infty > 0$ which means that $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ in the interval $]-\infty, \infty[$. Thus we have that
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n+1)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n}}{n!} \ \text{for} \ -\infty < x < \infty
$$
and
$$
f''(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(4n^2+2n)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n-1}}{n!} \ \text{for} \ -\infty < x < \infty
$$
but then to show that 
$$
-f''(x) + x^2f(x) = 3f(x) \ \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
I really have no idea how to. My TA told us that this question was pretty difficult and that we had to manipulate the sum and so on, but we have not really learned how to manipulate sums in general as this is not taught in my university (I think we are expected learn this on our own).

If I just plug in what we have I get
\begin{align}
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(4n^2+2n)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n-1}}{n!} + x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n+1}}{n!} & = \\
 -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(4n^2+2n)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n-1}}{n!} +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n+3}}{n!}
\end{align}
but I really have no idea how to proceed from here. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your power series has the compact form $$f(x)=x\exp(-x^2/2)$$ so that $$f'(x)=(1-x^2)\exp(-x^2/2)$$ and 
$$f''(x)=(-2x-x(1-x^2))\exp(-x^2/2)=-x(3-x^2)\exp(-x^2/2)=(x^2-3)f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

From $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n+1}$, we have
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n}$$
and
$$\begin{align}f''(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)(2n)}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n-1}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\,x^{2n-1}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n+3)}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n+1}\,.\end{align}$$
Consequently,
$$\begin{align}(x^2-3)\,f(x)&=x^2\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n+1}-3\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n+1}
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\,x^{2n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{3(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n+1}\\&=-3x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}-\frac{3(-1)^n}{2^nn!\,}\right)\,x^{2n+1}\\
&=-3x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n+3)}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n+1}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n+3)}{2^nn!}\,x^{2n+1}=f''(x)\,.\end{align}$$

---

Note that if the power series $\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,b_n\,x^n$ satisfies
$$g''(x)=(x^2-3)\,g(x)\,,\tag{#}$$
then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,(n+1)(n+2)\,b_{n+2}\,x^n=-3b_0-3b_1x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\,\big(b_{n-2}-3\,b_n\big)\,x^n\,.$$
Therefore, $b_2=-\dfrac{3}{2}\,b_0$, $b_3=-\dfrac12\,b_1$, and
$$(n+1)(n+2)\,b_{n+2}+3\,b_n-b_{n-2}=0\tag{*}$$
for all integers $n\geq 2$.

Write $e_n:=n!\,b_{2n}$ and $o_n:=n!\,b_{2n+1}$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.  From (*), we get
$$(2n+2)(2n+3)\,\frac{o_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+3\,\frac{o_n}{n!}-\frac{o_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=0\,,$$
or equivalently,
$$2\,(2n+3)\,o_{n+1}+3\,o_n-n\,o_{n-1}=0\,,$$
for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, with $o_0=b_1$ and $o_1=-\dfrac12\,b_1$.  By induction, $o_n=\left(-\dfrac12\right)^n\,b_1$, whence
$$b_{2n+1}=n!\,o_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\,b_1$$
for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.

On the other hand, we have
$$(2n+1)(2n+2)\,\frac{e_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+3\,\frac{e_n}{n!}-\frac{e_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=0\,,$$
or
$$2\,(2n+1)\,e_{n+1}+3\,e_n-n\,e_{n-1}=0$$
for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, with $e_0=b_0$ and $e_1=-\dfrac{3}{2}\,b_0$.  Unfortunately, [there is no simple expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5B%7B2%282n%2B1%29a%5Bn%2B1%5D%2B3a%5Bn%5D-n*a%5Bn-1%5D%3D%3D0%2Ca%5B0%5D%3D%3D1%2Ca%5B1%5D%3D%3D-3%2F2%7D%2Ca%5Bn%5D%2Cn%5D) for $e_n$ as far as I know.

However, as Lutz Lehmann remarked, $f(x)=x\,\exp\left(-\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)$.  We can use this to find all solutions $g(x)$ to (#) by using the technique known as [Reduction of Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order).

Consider the differential equation
$$u'(x)+\frac{2\,f'(x)}{f(x)}\,u(x)=0\,.$$
We see that
$$u'(x)-\frac{2(x^2-1)}{x}\,u(x)=0\,.$$
Hence,
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\,\big(x^2\,\exp(-x^2)\,u(x)\big)=0\,.$$
Therefore,
$$u(x)=-\dfrac{A}{x^2}\,\exp\left(x^2\right)$$
for some constant $A$.  That is,
$$\int\,u(x)\,\text{d}x=-A\,\left(\sqrt{\pi}\,\text{erfi}(x)-\frac{\exp(x^2)}{x}\right)+B$$
for some constant $B$, where $\text{erfi}$ is the [imaginary error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html):
$$\text{erfi}(x):=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,\int_{-x}^{+x}\,\exp(t^2)\,\text{d}t\,.$$  Since
$$g(x)=f(x)\,\int\,u(x)\,\text{d}x\,,$$
we get
$$g(x)=A\,\tilde{f}(x)+B\,{f}(x)\,,$$
where
$$\tilde{f}(x):=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)-\sqrt{\pi}\,x\,\text{erfi}(x)\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,.$$
Indeed, $A=g(0)$ and $B=g'(0)$, so 
$$\begin{align}g(x)&=g(0)\,\tilde{f}(x)+g'(0)\,f(x)\\
&=g(0)\,\Biggl(\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)-\sqrt{\pi}\,x\,\text{erfi}(x)\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\Biggr)+g'(0)\,x\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,.\end{align}$$ 
By the way, (#) is a [parabolic cylinder differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer! :) I know it is maybe a bit too much to ask for but do you mind explaining the steps you do when reindexing the sum: what is happening and why? I really can't figure it out. Sorry for asking so late.

Comment: @Mathias One way to manipulate indices is to create more dummy indices.  For example, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,nx^{n-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\,(m+1)\,x^m\,,$$ if you set $m:=n-1$.  This is essentially what I did in my answer.