# Prove that a power series satifies that $-f''(x) + x^2 f(x) = 3f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, power-series

> Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of a power series defined as
>   $$
> f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n+1}}{n!}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}
> $$
>
> **Question:**
>
> Find the power series for $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ and prove that 
>   $$
> -f''(x) + x^2f(x) = 3f(x) \ \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}
> $$

In an [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651583) I have argued for that $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ as we have a Power Series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$ with $a = 0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and convergence radius $R = \infty > 0$ which means that $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ in the interval $]-\infty, \infty[$. Thus we have that
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n+1)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n}}{n!} \ \text{for} \ -\infty < x < \infty
$$
and
$$
f''(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4n^2+2n)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n-1}}{n!} \ \text{for} \ -\infty < x < \infty
$$
but then to show that 
$$
-f''(x) + x^2f(x) = 3f(x) \ \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
is a struggle for me. We have not learned (and I am not even aware if we are going to learn) how to manipulate sums so I hope some of you can help me understand step by step how to solve this differential equation. I got an answer on this question a few days ago but I thought it was too difficult to understand so I hope you do not mind helping me again.

I start of by calculating the LHS:

\begin{align*}
    -f''(x) + x^2f(x) & = - \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4n^2+2n)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n-1}}{n!} \right) + x^2 \cdot \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n+1}}{n!} \right) \\
    & = 
\end{align*}
and now I think I have to get the same exponents for $x$ but how would one do this? How do I go from $x^{2n-1}$ to $x^{2n+1}$ by rearraging the sum? I can't see how going from $n = 0$ to $n=1$ as for $n=0$ the sum is just equal to $0$ would change anything. What do I do?

If you mind helping me would you please explain the steps you do if it is not too much to ask for.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
  S= -  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4n^2+2n)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n-1}}{n!} $$
Note that you have to change the indice of the  sum because it's zero for $n=0$. So we start the indice $n$ at $n=1$.
$$
  S= - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(4n^2+2n)(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n-1}}{n!} $$

Since we have $f$ on RHS which has $x^{2n+1}$ we will try to change our serie so it looks like that. We can change the indice $n$ so that the indice becomes $2m+1$
$$2n-1=2m+1 \implies n=m+1$$
Change the sum now. The series starts at $n=1 \implies m=0$:
$$
  S= - \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(4(m+1)^2+2(m+1))(-1)^{m+1}2^{-1-m}x^{2(m+1)-1}}{(m+1)!} $$
Or more simply:
$$
  S=  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m+3)(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)} $$
$$S=  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m)(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)}+ \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{3(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)}$$
And this series is just:
$$  S= 3f(x)+ \sum_{\color{red}{m=1}}^\infty \frac{2m(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)} $$
$$  S= 3f(x)+ x^2\sum_{{m=1}}^\infty \frac{2m(-1)^{m}x^{2m-1}}{2^m (m!)} $$
We need the series to look like $x^2f(x)$. But this last series starts at zero. We need to change our indice. 
$m=n+1$ Change the series:

$$  S= 3f(x)+ x^2\sum_{{n=0}}^\infty \frac{2(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{2^{n+1  } ((n+1)!)} $$
Or more simply:
$$  S= 3f(x)- x^2\sum_{{n=0}}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{2^n(n!)} $$
Finally as expected:
$$\boxed {S=3f(x)-x^2f(x)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try the same approach for $x^2f(x)$ and see if I get the desired result! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Try and see what you get.  @Mathias

Comment: I think I understand most of it by now but what happens here? "Or more simply:
$$
  S=  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m+3)(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)} $$
And this series is just:
$$  S= 3f(x)+ \sum_{\color{red}{m=1}}^\infty \frac{2m(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)} $$
$$  S= 3f(x)+ x^2\sum_{{m=1}}^\infty \frac{2m(-1)^{m}x^{2m-1}}{2^m (m!)} $$". If $m = 0$ we get $3x$ but where does $3f(x)$ then come from?

Comment: we had $2m+3$ it comes from the 3 split the series into two @Mathias

Comment: $S=  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m+3)(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)}$ means $$S=  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m)(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)}+ \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(3)(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)}$$ Do you see that the last series is just $3f(x)$ ? @Mathias

Comment: Thanks, and yes I do see that!

Comment: You need to practise again and again till you get it @Mathias

Comment: Absolutely. This is one of the harder questions in Analysis 2 exam so hopefully, I can practice more of these to get a better understanding. Than you very much for your help! :)

Comment: You're welcome @Mathias

Comment: I have one last question: How do you simply this? $$
  S= - \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(4(m+1)^2+2(m+1))(-1)^{m+1}2^{-1-m}x^{2(m+1)-1}}{(m+1)!} $$
Or more simply:
$$
  S=  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m+3)(-1)^{m}x^{2m+1}}{2^m (m!)} $$ I dont understand how $(4(m+1)^2+2(m+1)$ becomes $(2m+3)$? And how does $(m+1)!$ become $(m!)$?

Comment: You have a factorial at the denominator and $(m+1)!=m! (m+1) $ @Mathias

Comment: You simplify numerator and denominator by a factor of $m+1$ @Mathias

Comment: And you also have $2^{-1-m}=\dfrac 1 {2*2^m }$ @Mathias

Comment: So we have that $$ \frac{(4(m+1)^2+2(m+1))(-1)^mx^{2m+1}}{2 \cdot 2^m \cdot m!(m+1)} = \frac{(2(m+1)+2)(-1)^mx^{2m+1}}{2^m \cdot (m!)}$$ but this gives $2m+4$ and not $2m+3$?

Comment: $4(m+1)+2=4m+6$ that you simplify with the extra 2 at the denominator it gives $2m+3$ @Mathias

Comment: Ok I see I made a mistake. Thanks again for spending your time helping me! :)

Comment: You're welcome @Mathias

Comment: Does it matter to have $()$ around $n!$? Or does it not?

Comment: It dosent matter except if it may be ambiguous when there are factors around..@Mathias $2n! $ does it mean $(2n)!$ or does  it mean $2(n!)$ ...I put parentheses around  when i need to avoid this